# H14 - No web processes running on Heroku - previous posts with same concern doesn't resolve my issue. 550h eco dyno remaining but still not deployed

Tags: heroku, dyno

I have created a Flask-CRUD web application.

My app build is successful but is not deployed when I check the logs I get

```
`H14 No web processes running error`
```

I checked the dyno status through command
`heroku ps` and I got result
`**Eco dyno hours quota remaining this month: 550h 0m** (100%) Eco dyno usage for this app: 0h 0m (0%)`

My procfile is also named as Procfile (capital P)

```
web: gunicorn app: app
```

How can I resolve this my procfile is named as Procfile and I have also tried removing and adding back python buildpack

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue comes from the extra space in the Procfile after the `:`:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

Comment: I tried out that too, but it did not work

Comment: @ManviJha are you sure about the name of the app ? it is really `app` ?  What's the output of `heroku apps` ?

Comment: Yes, my app name is 'app' and the .py file is also `app`. And the output of `heroku apps`  also throws application error

Comment: could you share the error ?

Comment: `Build succeeded
2023-02-10T17:58:50.421311+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=dpsrecipeapp.herokuapp.com request_id=b1a52134-b9bf-424d-8a3c-dd0dab22b03e fwd="47.156.146.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-02-10T17:58:50.634271+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=dpsrecipeapp.herokuapp.com request_id=9ba89cd1-dea4-4825-b3a9-f71b0744d4bc fwd="47.156.146.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`